# C# Reflection > Nested attribute getValue > Object does not match target type

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, nested

I am unable to fixe the problem, all value are well retrived at the first level of the object but nested attributes value generate the error. I am sure that I need to adapt the getValue parameters object but I am unsure how. I have tried to pass nestedpropertyInfoArray, propertyInfo or req as parameter but still the same error.Any hints?

```
UpdatePhoneReq req = new UpdatePhoneReq();   
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in req.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
    {
        string attributValue = "";
        string attributName = propertyInfo.Name;
        Type attributType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        if (attributType == typeof(XFkType))
        {
            PropertyInfo[] nestedpropertyInfoArray = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetProperties();
            attributValue += "{";
            foreach (PropertyInfo subProperty in nestedpropertyInfoArray)
            {
                // --- > the GetValue below generates the error
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(subProperty.Name + "=" + subProperty.GetValue(req, null).ToString());
                attributValue += subProperty.Name + "=" + ",";

            }
            attributValue = attributValue.Substring(0, attributValue.Length - 1) + "}";
        }
        else
            attributValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(req, null) == null ? "" : propertyInfo.GetValue(req, null).ToString();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[" + propertyInfo.PropertyType + "]" + attributName + "=" + attributValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing parent object "req" to get value of the sub properties, you need to first find value of the property and pass it to get value of sub properties.

```
var propertyInfoValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(req, null);
```

then use this `propertyInfoValue`  for the `subProperty`.

```
subProperty.GetValue(propertyInfoValue , null)
```